# Clocking IT 0.99.3 Login Redirect After Year Change

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication

I am sorry but I am relatively new to the programming world and have run into an odd issue that I cannot overcome. At my company we use an open source ticketing system called Clocking IT version 0.99.3. Unfortunately, there does not appear to be any formal support for this program anymore which is why I am posting here. The issue that we are having is after the year change from 2014 to 2015 the login page no longer redirects to the home page after successful login, rather it redirects back to the login page to have you supply credentials again.

I validated this theory by setting the system time and date back to 12/31/2014 16:00:00 and can successfully log in, but if the date and time are restored to current that there is not successful login.

From what I know of the system, it is running in Linux using Apache / Ruby / and MYSQL. I have evaluated the login_controller.rb file and cannot find anything that stands out as the issue. I appreciate any advice that you guys can offer and can retrieve logs or configs upon request. Thank you.

Comment: There was a fix identified to this issue and I have pasted it below.

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jobsworth/Hvib7OJrzxM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem and I figured out the solution, edit the file /var/www/html/cit/config/environment.rb with command vim.

search the line below

ActionController::Base.session_options[:session_expires]= Time.local(2015,"jan") and change for

ActionController::Base.session_options[:session_expires]= Time.local(2035,"jan"), salve the file e restart the application.

Problem solved.

regards

André Paulino